# How to solve Flutter error: Could not find method versionName()

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Actually I get a very strange error when I try to run a Flutter build for Android.
First of all I want to show you the error. After that I show you the `Flutter doctor` result and specific code parts of my project.

**Error after running android project with `flutter run`**

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
> > Could not find method versionName() for arguments [1.0.0, null] on DefaultConfig_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null,
> > minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=18, mCodename='null'},
> > targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=28, mCodename='null'},
> > renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null,
> > renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null,
> > renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=8, versionName=null,
> > applicationId=de.danielederosa.virtualguestbook,
> > testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null,
> > testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null,
> > testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null,
> > mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[],
> > mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={},
> > mWearAppUnbundled=null} of type
> > com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 6s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
> exit code 1 Exited (sigterm)

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

**gradle.wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

**pubspec.yaml**

`version: 1.0.0+8`

It's interesting that it shows `versionName=null`, also if I overwrite the variable like this:

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "de.danielederosa.virtualguestbook"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName '1.0.0',
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Do you have any idea what could be the issue? Maybe some incompatibility with the gradle versions?

Answer (score 0):

Make it to default settings to see if it work:

This is my default flutter build.gradle (app)

```
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
```

and

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.teddichiiwa.example"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake on the line "versionName '1.0.0',"
there is a comma that should not be there.
Change the line to `versionName '1.0.0'`
I hope I have been helpful.